# Dealing with missing value in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I am using the Auto MPG dataset which contains missing values in the column/attribute `horsepower` in the form of `?` characters.

Hence when I use the code-

```
data.isnull.values.any()
```

OR

```
data["horsepower"].isnull.values.any()
```

Both of them return `False` since these codes work for NaN values or blank values.

How can I locate such missing values containing special character, which in my case happens to be `?` rather than the traditional NaN value(s).

Thanks!

Comment: replace `?` with `NaN` using `df.horsepower.replace('?',np.NaN, inplace=True)` Then go as usual

Comment: If you are reading your data from csv file then provide `na_values` as `?` in read_csv.  for more details visit https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I've verified my answer before posting. It's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert `?` to `NaN` first.
After then You can go for finding null values in it.

1) to convert `?` to `NaN` :

```
data.replace('?',np.NaN)
```

2) to find null values:

```
pd.isna(data['horsepower'])
```

it will return dataframe with series of `True/False`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) before checking `NaN`s:

```
data["horsepower"].replace('?',np.nan).isnull().values.any()
```

If `DataFrame` is created by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) add parameter [`na_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#na-values) for converting `?` to `NaN`s:

```
data = pd.read_csv(path, na_values=["?"])
data["horsepower"].isnull().values.any()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can define `na_values` as `?` or use the below:

```
df.replace(r'[\W]',np.nan,regex=True)
```

`\W` finds any character that is not a letter, numeric digit, or the underscore character.